# Is $\Box_{n\in\omega}[0,1]$ connected?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $\Box_{i\in I} X_i$ denote the [box product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) of the spaces $X_i$. The box product $\Box_{n\in\omega}\mathbb{R}$ is not connected, since the collection of bounded sequences is both open and closed.

Is $\Box_{n\in\omega}[0,1]$ connected?

Comment: The set of sequences $(a_n)$ such that $(n a_n)$ is bounded seems to be open and closed, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not connected.

Let $u=(u_n)$ be a sequence. For $\ell\in [0,1]$, define $$V_{u,\ell}=\{(v_n):\forall n\in \omega:|v_n-\ell|<\max(2^{-n},2|u_n-\ell|)\}.$$
Then $u\in V_{u,\ell}$ and $V_{u,\ell}$ is open.

Moreover, if $\ell$ is a limit point of $u$ and $v\in V_{u,\ell}$, then $\ell$ is a limit point of $v$.

Let $L_\ell$ be the set of sequences in $[0, 1]$ converging to $\ell$, and $L_\ell^c$ its complement. Then on the one hand, $L_0=\bigcup_{u\in L_0}V_{u,0}$, which is thus open. Its complement $L_0^c$ is $\bigcup_{u\in L_0^c,\ell\in P(u,0)}V_{u,\ell}$, where $P(u,\ell)$ is the set of limit points $\neq\ell$ of $u$. So it's open as well. Thus $L_0$ is clopen. (Similarly $L_\ell$ is open for every $\ell$.

Comment: It seems that $M_\ell$ and $L_\ell$ have gotten slightly mixed up?

Comment: Another way to see that $M_0$ is closed is to note that it is closed in the uniform topology, which is weaker than the box topology.

Comment: Yep $M_\ell=L_\ell$ sorry. Feel free to edit.