# Connected box products of Hausdorff spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

This is a follow-up on an [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297236/is-box-n-in-omega0-1-connected).

Let $\Box_{i\in I} X_i$ denote the [box product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) of the spaces $X_i$. Is there a Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ with $|X|>1$ such that $\Box_{n\in\omega}X$ connected?

Comment: While this does not completely answer your question, theorem 1.3(iii) of Scott W. William's chapter "Box Products" (chapter 4) in Kunen & Vaughan's *Handbook of Set Theoretical Topology* (1984) states that the box product of an infinite family of non-discrete Hausdorff completely regular topological spaces is never connected.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for this hint!

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, Of course if $X$ has an isolated point then $\Box_{n\in\omega}X$ is not connected. It also seems to me that William only uses regularity of $X$ in the theorem that you mention. So one has to look only for connected Hausdorff non-regular spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is the [Irrational slope topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000067) then the closures of any two non-empty open sets must intersect. It easily follows that $\Box_{n\in\omega}X$ is connected. Note that $X$ is Hausdorff but not regular. It seems (see the comments to the OP) that there are no $T_3$ examples.

Comment: Great, Ramiro - I didn't know about that topology, thanks for making me aware of it!